# Do I need to delete node_modules before running pnpm install?

Tags: pnpm

Working with packageManager: pnpm.
Working in a project that commits changes to git, we are changes branches during work.
Checking in into a new branch that contains changes in one or both: package.json, pnpm-lock.yaml. We detect this change and and decide we need to update node_modules.

**Do we need to delete node_modules before running pnpm install ?**

Working with npm it was best practice to delete node_modules to be ensure all packages with their exact version as in package-lock file will be installed, otherwise modules that are already been exist in node_modules might be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need to delete node_modules.

The only case when a deletion might be recommended is when changing some configuration settings in `.npmrc`. But even in those cases pnpm mostly deletes node_modules automatically.

Any scenario that requires manual deletion can be considered a bug.